# Store Random ID for MySql Table

Tags: mysql, random, sql-order-by

I have a large (1.5M-2M) record `MySQL` table which I am indexing into `Sphinx`.

I need the IDs to be random/non-sequential due to the fact I am doing a two-level order (`order by FieldA DESC,FieldB DESC`) which then by default orders by ID. This gives me undesirable results, since I store my data by Vendor and I'd like more random vendors once the FieldA and FieldB Order is implemented.

Since I could not figure out how to do this on the fly, I tried the following, which I tested on small tables to generate random unique integers:

```
-- Update IGNORE Table
Set ID=FLOOR(RAND() * 2000000);
```

But after an hour or so gave up on that approach

Is there some efficient way to generate random IDs?

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48035801/6313073) for a couple of ways you can create a unique, random ID @user3649739.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the date as a unique ID and then encrypt that using a secret key:

```
SET ID = HEX(AES_ENCRYPT(CONCAT(NOW(), RAND()), 'secret_key'));
```

Here's a cryptographically less secure alternative [*(to enhance performance)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035707/store-random-id-for-mysql-table/48035801#comment83041563_48035801):

```
SET ID = MD5(CONCAT(NOW(), RAND()));
```

**Note:** Both of the above suggestions use a random salt along with the date to evitate timestamp collisions that would otherwise exist, if more than one rows would be inserted in the same second.

Comment: Depending on the insert rate, I would add a random salt generated using `RAND()` to prevent timestamp collisions.  You may also achieve better performance by using a weak hash function like MD5 instead of full-blown encryption.  There is no benefit in cryptographic security here.

Comment: Agreed. I included a version using `MD5` and implemented your suggestion regarding the salt as well. Thanks @MTCoster 

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to randomize the orders without conflicts is to randomize the *rows* and assign a new monotonically increasing id.

The example below assumes you have no other concurrent inserts running (otherwise it causes a race condition).

```
SET @id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable);

UPDATE MyTable
SET ID = @id:=@id+1
ORDER BY RAND();
```

I renumber starting at 1 higher than the previous max id, because if we tried to randomly renumber within the same range of id's, it would have a high chance of causing collisions.